# Getting error in Jenkins while deploying war file. Working in tomcat 9. But not in tomcat 10

Tags: maven, jenkins, tomcat

[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wallmart/target/maven-web-application.war to container Tomcat 9.x Remote with context null
[/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wallmart/target/maven-web-application.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wallmart/target/maven-web-application.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wallmart/target/maven-web-application.war]
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:104)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1175)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:47)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:816)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:765)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:709)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1924)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/maven-web-application] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99)
... 20 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/maven-web-application] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1175)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:47)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:816)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:765)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:709)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1924)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

It work for me.
Adding to building before deploy
shell script:

```
curl -u userTomcat:password http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/
```